# Sort array with ÅÄÖ

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm totally new to iPhone/OSX development and I'm trying to sort an NSMutableArray filled with objects in alphabetical order but I fail. Items starting with Å or Ä ends up with items starting with A and items starting with Ö ends up with items starting with O. I have tried different sorting methods that I have found here on Stackoverflow but none of them seems to work (for me at least)

```
    NSSortDescriptor* stationDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray* descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:stationDescriptor];
    [stations sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];


    [stations sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Station* obj1, Station* obj2){
        return [[obj1 name] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:[obj2 name]];
    }];
```

Ok, progress! I have been successful in getting this to work by changing the language on the emulator to Swedish, is there any way I can get the same result when the phone is set to English? I know in C# you can send in a reference to a specific culture when sorting/comparing strings.

/Viktor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) gives you the answer.

You are using [localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHEBIF) and the docs for this state

> blah blah blah
>
> **See Also**
> – compare:options:range:locale:

So jumping to the docs for [compare:options:range:locale:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options:range:locale:) you can figure it out. You'll need something like

```
return [[obj1 name] compare:[obj2 name]
                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [obj1 length])
                     locale:whateverLocaleYouWant];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be NSMakeRange(0, [[obj1 name] length]) ?

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, I added the  NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"nb_NO"];
 and it started working for me.